# What is the subtextual meaning of the kittle vs kettle in Krazy Kat on 1918-10-03 - Friday?

Tags: comics, george-herriman, krazy-kat

I'm trying to guess at the implied meaning of the conversation in this Krazy Kat daily strip from [1918-10-03](https://www.comicstriplibrary.org/display/49):

> Ignatz: For goodness sake, Krazy, don't call a 'kettle' a 'kittle'.
> Krazy: What must I call a 'kittle', Ignatz?
>
> Ignatz: Call it a 'kettle' Krazy: A kettle?
>
> Krazy: All right, I'll call a 'kittle' a 'kettle'.

In the first panel, Ignatz admonishes Krazy to call something a kettle rather than 'kittle.' In the second panel Ignatz is standing on a pair of crossed swords and in the background is a tree-like figure in the shape of a circle enclosing a cross.

To "cross swords" is to have a dispute or argument.

I'm wondering if kettle might refer to a kettle boiling over, like a dispute that might overheat to the point of being out of control because of a disagreement over property lines, for example. Or possibly a tempest in a tea kettle (rather than a teapot), in which a minor dispute produces a huge argument? It seems likely that this also refers to the phrase, "kettle calling the pot black," which adds additional racial overtones to the conversation.

Sometimes two parties are referring to the same thing but respond differently to the thing's meaning based on which perspective each party uses to make sense of the world. For example, a social construct can impose restraints but sometimes provide an opportunity for resistance. In *Romeo & Juliet*, being a Capulet vs being a Montague imposes pre-existing constraints on the main characters who fight tragically against fate.

So, instead of Shakespeare's phrase "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet," it's Ignatz insisting that Krazy call a 'kittle' a kettle. Krazy seems okay with that while seeming to maintain the mental meaning of the object being a 'kittle.'

Does the cross inscribed in a circle refer to anything? Google image search turns up some swords crossed through a shield and a few logos based on the same motif. Could it be a [ring cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringed_cross) or a [sun cross / wheel cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_cross)?

Could kettle possibly refer to a kettle helm, an oblique reference to fighting a battle? crossed swords + stylized cross shield + kettle helmet = battle?

[image: Krazy Kat on 1918-10-03 - Friday]
[image: swords crossed through a shield]

Comment: The crossed swords are [a dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_sword_dances#/media/File:Scottish_Sword_Dance_2.jpg), not an argument. Note the movement lines

Comment: In context, the circle cross is likely a [celtic cross](https://agraveinterest.blogspot.com/2011/03/celtic-cross-in-cemetery.html?m=0), possibly a gravestone.

Comment: The term [kittle is a Scots Gaelic word for kettle](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/kettle). I believe Ignatz is accusing Krazy of being or sounding Scottish (hence mocking him by dancing in a Scottish jig over swords with a Celtic cross in the background) because he uses the older form of the word

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it's worth noting that a number of Krazy Kat strips were about slight variations of a word. I have fond (if vague) memories of one involving the police being informed of an upcoming crime by telegram, telephone, and eventually telepathy.

Comment: @valorum That’s Scots, not Gaelic. Gaelic for kettle is *an coire*.

Comment: Maybe thinking too much? https://www.comicstriplibrary.org/display/244

Comment: I admit to overthinking but the occasional Latin phrases, the esoteric vocabulary usage, & the oblique mythology references that pepper other strips spark some gear turning on my part. This is the video that got me started: Krazy Kat, the Poetics of Passing, Michael Tisserand https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMwg_LPQggE